# How to convert data into binned arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have pandas dataframe:

```
df 
value
50
30
40
...
```

I want to turn into a numpy array with shape (n/5, 5) with n being the number of rows in the df:

```
array([[50,  30,  40, 10, 50], ... ])
```

How can I achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for `df.values.reshape(len(df)//5, 5)` ?

Comment: Is `n` a multiple of `5`?

Comment: @SomeDude Thank you! How can I do the reverse of this? If I have the array with shape (len(df)/5, 5), how can I get to the original dataframe?

Comment: My earlier comment was assuming that number of rows is a multiple of 5. Now to get it back to your original shape (having only 1 column in your df). You could do: `shaped_array.reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: @mozway how can I do this if n is not a multiple of 5? do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @SomeDude if the number of rows is not equal to 5, how would you go about it? I have a bunch of csv files that I want to read from a folder in a for loop, and apply this transformation somewhere in the loop, but not all file lenght are divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[50,40,30,40,50],columns=['value'])
lst = df['value'].tolist()
arr = np.array([lst[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(lst), 5)])
arr = arr.reshape((len(df)//5, 5))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?